# Function to search sequential values on a list

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
list = [
   [2, 'A', '1'],
   [6, 'A', '2'],
   [6, 'S', '3'],
   [9, 'A', '4'],
   [6, 'A', '5'],
   [6, 'A', '6'],
   [6, 'S', '7'],
   [9, 'A', '8'],
   [9, 'A', '9'],
   [6, 'A', '10'],
   [10, 'S', '11'],
   [13, 'S', '12'],
   [13, 'S', '13'],
   [16, 'A', '14']
]
```

The first position of list is the level, the second the type of node and the third is the value.

I need to concatenate all values that have a higher level than before (i-1). I can have multiple A and S in each level, but every time I find a S type I need to still search until I find a higher level of S or A type. My desired output:

```
['1.2', '1.3.4', '1.5', '1.6', '1.7.8', '1.7.9', '1.10.11.13.14']
```

I tried to achieve this output with the following code:

```
def concat_levels(levels):
     result = []
     stack = []
    
     for level in levels:
        num, typ, name = level
        
        while stack and stack [-1][0] >= num:
           stack.pop()
 
        if typ == 'A':
           stack.append((num,name))
        elif typ == 'S':
           if stack:
              current_path = '.'.join([x[1] for x in stack])
              result.append(current_path + '.' + name)
     return result
```

However, when I run my function I got the following output:

```
['1.3', '1.7', '1.10.11', '1.10.12', '1.10.13']
```

Apparently my function is appending only on `type == 'S'`, but why?

CONTEXT: This list is an abstracted version of a pyspark dataframe schema where A represents array type and S represents Structure type. Why 12 is not in the output? Because 12 is a struct (S type). It’s 1.10.11.13.14 Because the level 16 represents that value 14 is inside the value and level 13 structure. Since the schema is ordered, every time there is two S types in the same level, if an A type appears after a S type, then the last S type should be considered (always respecting the level rule)

Comment: Why `1.10.11.13.14`? Shouldn't it be `1.10.11.12.14`

Comment: Hey @TimRoberts, sorry about that. It was a typo error. You are right. I edited my input and output. Now they are correct.

Comment: @TheMaster Because `13` value happens before `14` and after `12`

Comment: Missing the logic of *every time I find a S type I need to still search until I find a higher level of S or A type*. At `[10, 'S', '11'],`, we have `1.10.11`. From here, we have `[13, 'S', '12'],
   [13, 'S', '13'],
   [16, 'A', '14']`. `13` is a higher "level" of S. We have two `13` levels with value `12` and `13`. Why are we skipping over `12` and going to `13`?

Comment: I also don't understand why 12 shouldn't be in the output

Comment: @TheMaster @wjandrea I’ve edited the question again to explain the context of my problem and why `12` should not be appended. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly and if you're tempted to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you want to [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) a sequence of the [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.last.html) values (*seen at a given level*) along an [`expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) window, if and only if the level [`is_monotonic_increasing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.is_monotonic_increasing.html) and doesn't close on `"S"` :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list_, columns=["level", "type", "value"])

DIFF = df["level"].diff(); HEAD = df.at[0, "value"]

def seq(wd):
    diff = DIFF.loc[wd.index]
    not_dup = wd["level"].ne(wd["level"].shift())
    is_mi = wd.loc[not_dup, "level"].is_monotonic_increasing
    return (
        wd.loc[(diff.le(0) if is_mi else diff.lt(0))[::-1].idxmax() :]
        .groupby("level")["value"].last()
    )

sequences = [
    ".".join([HEAD, *wd.pipe(seq)])
    for wd in list(df.expanding())[1:]
    if (wd["type"].iat[-1] != "S") and not (
        DIFF.lt(0).iat[wd.index[-1]]
        and DIFF.shift(-1).gt(0).iat[wd.index[-1]]
    )
]
```

Output :

```
print(sequences)

# ['1.2', '1.3.4', '1.5', '1.6', '1.7.8', '1.7.9', '1.10.11.13.14']
```

Windows :

```
 level type value   w1     w2     w3     w4     w5     w6     w7  
     2    A     1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1  
     6    A     2    2      -      -      -      -      -      -  
     6    S     3    -      3      -      -      -      -      -  
     9    A     4    -      4      -      -      -      -      -  
     6    A     5    -      -      5      -      -      -      -  
     6    A     6    -      -      -      6      -      -      -  
     6    S     7    -      -      -      -      7      7      -  
     9    A     8    -      -      -      -      8      -      -  
     9    A     9    -      -      -      -      -      9      -  
     6    A    10    -      -      -      -      -      -     10  
    10    S    11    -      -      -      -      -      -     11  
    13    S    12    -      -      -      -      -      -     -  
    13    S    13    -      -      -      -      -      -     13  
    16    A    14    -      -      -      -      -      -     14
```